# Unable to pass object Name in the SObject for loop to call methods Dynamically

Tags: apex, sobject, dynamic-soql, sobjecttype

I am trying to optimize my code, instead of using object Name in if else I want to pass the SObject parameter and combine below code

Instead of using separate objects I am trying to merge if else into one loop and pass the SObject parameter dynamically based on the object Name, how can I achieve that.
Based on this, I'll have to use the similar logic and modify my queueable class, there is a lot of redundant code.. Please advice how to achieve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is more general points than a direct solution to your problem.

You can certainly write methods that accept the base type `SObject` and then use the `get` and `set` methods that all instances support to access and update field values. There are many other methods available too - see [SObject Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Custom objects all have these [Custom Object Standard Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_objectfields.htm&type=5). So you can rely on being able to read a custom object name like this:

```
SObject sob = ...;
String name = (String) sob.get('Name');
```

or set it like this:

```
String value = '...';
sob.put('Name', value);
```

and it is possible to hard-code other field names as strings, though they will all have API names that end in `__c` as that suffix is automatically added and must be used.

But sometimes it is worth moving away from strings to make use of `SObjectField` and `SObjectType` tokens. These are part of the access mechanism to get hold of [describe information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm): detailed descriptions of SObjects and SObject fields.

When you have an `SObject` you can get its `SObjectType` via its `getSObjectType()` method. An `Id` also has a `getSObjectType()` method. So, for example, starting from an `Id` you can get a custom object's name like this:

```
Id customId = ...;
String name = (String) Database.query(''
    + ' select 'Name'
    + ' from ' + id.getSObjectType()
    + ' where Id = :customId'
).get('Name');
```

So you can write non-type specific code. And where you need to do something type specific you can check the type and branch in your code accordingly:

```
if (customId.getSObjectType() == MyCustomObject__c.SObjectType) {
    ...
}
```

**PS**

In response to the comment "how can I get the SObject name as Account in this":

```
for(SObject sob : sObjectSelector.selectByExternalID(allMasterChildIdSet, objectName)) {
    ...
}
```

it looks like you may already have it in the `objectName` variable. But if a different object type is returned:

```
for(SObject sob : ...) {

    // As a type object
    SObjectType type = sob.getSObjectType();

    // As a type name string
    String typeAsString = String.valueOf(type);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @Keith.. just for my clarification could you please tell me how can I get the SObject name as Account in this-- for(SObject acc : sObjectSelector.selectByExternalID(allMasterChildIdSet, objectName))